# Filter Sequence of Record Types by Property

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I have an ordered sequence of the following type:

```
type Comparison<'a when 'a :> IKey > = {Id: string; src: 'a; dest: 'a}
```

What I'd like to do is where there is more than one record with the same `Id` to only take the latest record in the sequence for each id (the sequence has been generated from ordered query results) as well as records where the Id is not shared with other records.

Is there a method in F# to generate a new sequence in this way?

Comment: if the underlying implementation of your sequence is guaranteed to preserve order, you just have to use `Seq.filter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
items 
|> Seq.groupBy (fun x -> x.Id) 
|> Seq.map (snd >> Seq.last)
```

This groups the items into a sequence of tuples, where the first item is the ID and the second is a sequence of elements with that Id.

Then the map applies Seq.last to the second elements of those tuples.